# Splitting the data-- New scenario

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am able to split the data into three different categories. Since I found one scenario which is not been handling by the query used by me. Below is the query with couple of examples:

QUERY:-

```
with XYZ as (
```

select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Antarctica, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Arctic, Language: English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North Arigina, Language(s): English,Spanish, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North America, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Language: German, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachment(s): 8, Circuit: Canada Abcdef & dfasghi Network, Language(s): English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachment(s): 1, Circuit: Biotechnology Xyzabc [National], Language(s): English, Words: 493' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: International Hijkl Wireless (sel-srvc), Language(s): English,Dutch, Words: 357' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: ching Kong, Language(s): Chinese (Traditional), Words: 414' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachment(s): 1, Circuit: Major A.B. Marketing, Language(s): English, Words: 400'  as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
union all
select 'Attachments: 1, Language: English, Webcenter Postings: AMDA-5K2DAC, Words: 343' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
)
SELECT SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
--regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\s([a-zA-Z0-9 \[\] \&]+)(,\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit1",
--regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\s([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\- \[\] \&]+)(,\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit2",
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\s([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\- \[\] \& \.]+)(,\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit2",
NVL( regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Language\(s\):\s([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\, (@"\Webcenter Postings|\b")]+)(,\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e'),
REGEXP_REPLACE( regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, '(Language:.*), Words', 1, 1, 'e'), '[ ]*Language: '  )) AS "LanguageString",
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Words:\s([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)(,\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Words"
FROM XYZ;

---

'Attachments: 1, Language: English, Webcenter Postings: AMDA-5K2DAC, Words: 343'          `--> this is the example where I am getting captured with some other words in language string . Instead of getting captured language as English, I am getting English, Webcenter Postings: AMDA-5K2DAC .

Note: This question is repeated couple of times in stack overflow, but the scenario found is new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you also have to account for the `(`, `)`, and `-` character in that substring you'll have to add those to your regex:

```
regexp_substr(SOID, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\(\\)\\- \\[\\] \\&]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit"
```

Comment: Hi , since I found a new scenario, i just changed the question.